# How to merge two rows into a single row in mysql

Tags: mysql

The required table should merge two rows from the original table and the description in two rows should be appended into a single required table

Original Table

```
id  quantity    item_number description unit_price  Total   returns
1   100         MISC SALES  Misc Sales  0.3         30      ABC
2   NULL        NULL        XXXXXX      NULL        NULL    ABC
3   200         MISC SALES  Misc Sales  0.45        90      ABC
4   NULL        NULL        YYYYYY      NULL        NULL    ABC
```

Required Table

```
id  quantity    item_number description         unit_price  Total   returns
1   100         MISC SALES  Misc Sales XXXXXX   0.3         30      ABC
2   200         MISC SALES  Misc Sales YYYYYY   0.45        90      ABC
```

Comment: Where did you get such a table?

Comment: what is your criteria of merge? is it quantity?

Comment: @bansi: Above table was parsed from a pdf in which the description is long so that it appear in 2 rows. All 4 rows are parsed from a single pdf 'ABC' which is in 'returns' column. So I need to merge the description into a single row. Parsing logic is out of my bounds which I cannot go ahead and change this while parsing itself.

Comment: so you want to merge first and second row then 3rd and 4th and so on (consecutive ids). let me try

Comment: @bansi : yeah exactly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select round(id/2),quantity,,item_number,GROUP_CONCAT(" " ,description) , unit_price,Total, returns 
from (

 select id,quantity,item_number, description, unit_price,Total, returns from table1 where id%2=1 

UNION

 select id-1,quantity,item_number, description ,unit_price,Total, returns from table1 where id%2=0 
) as temp group by id;
```

Comment: you have additional comas quantity`,,`item_number. remove that and it works except the id op wanted was a running number.